# voice recognition constantly in background android

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, voice, vosk

FfhggtffgtfgtgftI want develop application that whenever it recognizes a keyword it does something. it needs to be in listening mode all the time, in backgeound too.
I was exposed to [this](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/android) and [this](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/). I treid run it but it is not work when I am speaking.
actually I read it still doesn't support my native language. is that the reason?
I want to know how it works? does it is doing speach to text and saved it in assets files? does it is run in background? does it is used AI models? how it behaves when two apps need mic resource in parallel? noises? does it is work with Neural Networks API? how can I start developing such a thing?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is great you tried [Vosk offline speech recognition on Android](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-android-demo), here are some answers to your questions:

> actually I read it still doesn't support my native language.

If you are about Hebrew, we might support it in the future, and you can build it yourself.

> is that the reason?

You didn't provide enough information to answer this, please explain a bit more what is "it is not work"

> I want to know how it works?

Extensive documentation on speech recognition is available on lectures, courses and books. You can find some introduction here for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q67z7PTGRi8

> does it is doing speech to text and saved it in assets files?

It does speech to text, but it doesn't save results into assets, it just displays them. You can not modify assets, they are static.

> does it is run in background?

Yes

> does it is used AI models?

Sure

> how it behaves when two apps need mic resource in parallel?

In android it is not possible to record audio from two apps in parallel, second one will be blocked.

> noises?

It is robust to noises.

> does it is work with Neural Networks API?

No, it is portable

> how can I start developing such a thing?

Get some basic understanding and start writing the code. If you have further questions you can ask them in the [Telegram chat](https://t.me/speech_recognition_help)

Comment: thanks a lot. in AI the meaning is mechine learning. right? also what you meant in it is portable? thank you again!